# Getting value of PHYS_OFFSET in ARM linux user space

Tags: linux, embedded, arm

I have an embedded linux system running on cortexA8.I understand the kernel symbol PHYS_OFFSET represents the physical start address of RAM  http://www.kernelport.org/defines.html. I need the value of this symbol in user space for some validation purpose in some shell script that runs after kernel has booted up. The /proc filesystem doesnt have this info. Pls let me know if I can get this value by some means.

Comment: Have you looked in `/sys`?  If nothing handy there, creating a kernel module to expose this would be fairly straightforward.

Comment: `grep PHYS_OFFSET /boot/config-\`uname -r\``

Comment: @mux the /boot folder is empty. How is the /boot/config file created ?

Comment: @Marko I am looking at /sys. Not found anything yet though

Comment: @Badri try `zgrep PHYS_OFFSET /proc/config.gz`

Comment: @mux Thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunately only CONFIG_PAGE_OFFSET is present in config. uImage with different PHYS_OFFSET is created from the same zImage by passing different params to mkimage.So I think this info may not be available in config file but should be embedded in the uImage.Do you agree ? I checked dmesg trace and that too does not have PHYS_OFFSET printed.Maybe creating kernel modules is the only option ?

Comment: Do you have no idea about what PHYS_OFFSET is or would you like to have something variable? Normally memory.h generated by Linux contains that value and you need to include that in your app. I would probably "cat /proc/iomem|grep System" and do some processing with those values to calculate PHYS_OFFSET. Assuming you are looking for ARM's 0x80000000.

Comment: @auselen PHYS_OFFSET is variable. There are different builds having different value for PHYS_OFFSET . I was looking at getting the value of __pv_phys_offset symbol actually. But your idea of cat /proc/iomem|grep System works great. Does it represent the real RAM address ranges ? How do I accept your comment as the answer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to utilize I/O memory map by reading `/proc/iomem` which should tell about `System RAM` - all address in `iomem` is real / physical addresses.

This is from my Android phone which has a 1GB ram (0xbfffffff - 0x80000000).

```
$cat /proc/iomem
...
80200000-88cfffff : System RAM
  80300000-80c708cf : Kernel text
  80d00000-80fb1dcb : Kernel data
88d00000-88d00fff : ramdumpinfo
88d01000-88d04fff : amsslog
88de0000-88dfffff : ram_console
90000000-ab4fffff : System RAM
b9a02000-bfffffff : System RAM
```

You somehow need to convert the range specified in **System RAM** to what you need.